# Как взять уникальные данные из List<string>()

Tags: c#, list

Есть два списка list1() и list2()

В

```
list1 
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

В

```
 list2 
  2;item0
  3;item1
  5;item2
```

Надо чтобы брались уникальные данные из первого списка и уникальные данные из второго списка list2.Split(';')[0]. Как это сделать? Есть идея использовать `Except` правда не совсем понятно как это сделать. В итоге должен получится список

```
list3
1
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

> чтобы брались уникальные данные из первого списка и уникальные данные из второго

Можно с помощью метода Merge:

```
IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> l1, IEnumerable<T> l2) {
   return l1.Except(l2).Concat(l2.Except(l1));
}
```

---

Код для проверки

```
class Item { public int Id; public string Text; } 
var l1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var l2 = new List<Item> { 
           new Item { Id = 2, Text = "item0" }, 
           new Item { Id = 3, Text = "item1" }, 
           new Item { Id = 5, Text = "item2" } 
           };
var l3 = Merge(l1, l2.Select(i => i.Id)).ToList();   // результат: { 1, 4, 5 }
```

Comment: Я бы назвал не `Merge`, а `Xor` что ли.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что у Вас там за типы, но если предположить, что и там, и там строки, то можно сделать как-то так:

```
var first = new List<string>()
            {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
var second = new List<string>()
            {"2;item0", "3;item1", "5;item2" };
var secondAsFirst = second.Select(str => str.Split(';')[0]);
var third = first.Except(secondAsFirst).ToList();
third.AddRange(secondAsFirst.Except(first));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.Except(list2).Concat(list2.Except(list1))
```